# How to run a separate thread on app startup in Django 1.11

Tags: python, mysql, django, multithreading

I have a Django project that I requires the database being updated daily. I want to do this by having a separate thread, instantiated at startup in apps.py, that downloads a large (>2GB) csv file every day, then adds all entries in that file to the project's MySQL database.

After Googling, it seems the preferred way of doing this (at least as of ~3 years ago) is by using Celery to create a distributed task queue and incorporating it with a broker. However, having no experience with Celery, or any distributed systems, this seems overly complex and is definitely overkill for my project. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: A simple way to do this is to write a django management command and run that as a cron job. https://coderwall.com/p/k5p6ag/run-django-commands-using-cron

Comment: @HåkenLid Wow. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm actually updating from multiple .csv files so I can write a command around each one for testing, and then have a parent command that does all of them at once in production. 

If you want to write it out as an answer I'll mark it as correct.